# Configuring Tectite PHP Formmail Script

Tags: php, html, formmail

Im trying to use Tectite Formmail script on a contact form. I read their documentation on setting it (formmail.php file). But confused on setting form data receiver's email address. For example i want to get form data to "admin@zahedkamal.com". Can anybody instruct me on setting it? im not good at PHP so not understanding their script properly...

Here is my form code

```
<form id="contact_us" action="formmail.php" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="recipients" value="admin@zahedkamal.com" />

        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Submission" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="auto-style31">full name </span>
                <input name="Text1" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="auto-style31">email </span>
                <input name="Text2" data-validation="email" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="auto-style31">volunteer </span>
                <input name="Checkbox1[]" type="checkbox" />

                <span class="auto-style31">stallholder </span>
                <input name="Checkbox1[]" type="checkbox"  />

                <span class="auto-style31">sponsorship </span>
                <input name="Checkbox1[]" type="checkbox" />

                <span class="auto-style31">membership </span>
                <input name="Checkbox1[]" type="checkbox"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="auto-style26">other</span>

                <textarea name="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="1"></textarea>

            </div>

            <input type="reset" value="reset" /><span class="auto-style31">
            </span>
            <input class="auto-style31" name="Submit1" style="width: 70px" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this now, so I'm answering even though it's probably too late!

The best way to get support for Tectite FormMail is to email us via our contact email address.

Your $TARGET_EMAIL setting in FormMail should be:

```
$TARGET_EMAIL = array('^admin@zahedkamal\.com$');
```

Hope that helps!